# MongoDB Filter with Interval and division in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongoose, filter

I have some trouble to filter the interval with perform division on property of collection class.

**Code :**

```
if(sPacketMSItem.DollerPerCarat.HasValue && sPacketMSItem.DollerPerCarat.Value > 0)
                filter = filter & Builders<Packet>.Filter.Gte(c => c.NetAmount / c.Weight, sPacketMSItem.DollerPerCarat - 30 )
                                                  & Builders<Packet>.Filter.Lte(c => c.NetAmount / c.Weight, sPacketMSItem.DollerPerCarat + 30);
```

but it give `sPacketMSItem.DollerPerCarat` is some time nullable so this query can't filter the property data and give the execption.

**Exeception :**

```
Unable to determine the serialization information for c => Convert((c.NetAmount / c.Weight), Nullable`1).
```

i am not understand why this happen. Please give me some explanation on this.

**Note :** 
I have complex query. There are 50 Builder filter like this one

```
filter = filter & Builders<Packet>.Filter.In(c => c.SerialNo, srNo);
```

and in addition filter is upper one(divide one). so i have doing trouble to do it.
please explain me more if you understand my problem.

**Edit :**

I have create this way match

```
var group = new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"_id", "$ID"}
                     };

var match = new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument()
                        .Add("$and", new BsonArray()
                                .Add(new BsonDocument()
                                        .Add("$gte", new BsonArray()
                                                .Add(new BsonDocument()
                                                        .Add("$divide", new BsonArray()
                                                                .Add("$nA")
                                                                .Add("$wT")
                                                        )
                                                )
                                                .Add(1200.0)
                                        )
                                )
                                .Add(new BsonDocument()
                                        .Add("$lte", new BsonArray()
                                                .Add(new BsonDocument()
                                                        .Add("$divide", new BsonArray()
                                                                .Add("$nA")
                                                                .Add("$wT")
                                                        )
                                                )
                                                .Add(2400.0)
                                        )
                                )
                            ));


var pipeline = new[] { match };
```

now use it like this

```
var abc = await packetCollection.AggregateAsync(pipeline, options).Group(group).Match(filter).ToListAsync();
```

it give me following error.
**ERROR :**

> /Users/lalitdevani/Documents/AasthaSalesWebApi/Aastha/_git/Sales.WebApi/Biz.DAL/MongoRepositoriesCustom/SalesCRMRepository/MarketSheet/MarketSheetRepository.cs(54,54):
>   Error CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   'IMongoCollection.AggregateAsync(PipelineDefinition, AggregateOptions, CancellationToken)' cannot be inferred
>   from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. (CS0411)
>   (Biz.DAL)

Any help will be appreciated.